# Why is the program form not loading when accessing file?

Tags: c#, winforms, file

With the below code, I've tested it out and the loading of the form works fine standalone, but when the program goes to check if a file exists, the form doesn't load properly and I'm at a loss as to what to do.  Is there another method of checking to see if a file exists that I could use in this instance?

**EDIT** I've made a new 'startup' form to run the file exists check, but it still doesn't work.  Again the form loads, but the contents of the form don't and the form itself freezes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace program1
{
    public partial class Startup : Form
    {
        public Startup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Startup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcons norm = new notifyIcons();
            Settings set = new Settings();
            set.Show();
            string curFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\age.txt";
            if (File.Exists(curFile))
            {
                norm.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                set.Show();
                for (;;) 
                {
                    if (File.Exists(curFile)) norm.Show(); this.Close();
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've taken the advice from both @SimonWhitehead, but the above code ought to be working shouldn't it?  I'm desperate for any advice, as I'm so close to finishing now!

Comment: I've worked on it subsequently, and made a completely new forms.  Again, when I start the program, it realizes the file doesn't exist, but it loads the form with the contents blacked out.  Interestingly enough, the only thing that loads is the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the following code in the main form, it seemed to work a treat!  I think the critical part was Application.DoEvents();
Thanks for all of your assistance

```
InitializeComponent();
            set.Show();
            set.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

            string curFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\age.txt";
            if (File.Exists(curFile)) goto Labelx;
            set.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            for (; ; ) { Application.DoEvents(); if (File.Exists(curFile)) break; }
            set.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            Labelx:TextReader reader = File.OpenText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\age.txt");
```

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea what this code is supposed to do.. but I can tell you why its not working.

```
while (ageFileExists)
```

That is never false. Therefore, your loop will continually loop... forever. You need to set it false somehow in the loop. I have no idea what sort of rules govern that though.

The reason the form doesn't load is because the loop never exits.. and so the message loop that makes the window do *anything* can never continue processing window messages.

If you can give more context around what you're trying to do I could help you with a proper solution. As it stands though, I can only see the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include the fact that the variable 'ageFileExists' is automatically set to false.  Hence, when the file exists, would the 'while' loop exit?

Comment: If its false then it will never execute. What about `curFile`.. does that exist? If it does.. your `goto` will always fire. You need to show more code.

Comment: The problem is that the code above works fine, it's just that when it tries to find a file, it fails.  The main question I have is: is there another method to determine if a file exists that doesn't halt the program?

Comment: None of the "does a file exist" methods halt the program. You have a logic problem if that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(ageFileExists)
{
    if (File.Exists(curFile)) ageFileExists = true;
    set.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

If that file exists you have an infinite loop.  You never set `ageFileExists` to false and that loop does nothing at all. And where does that label go?  I seriously doubt you need to be using `goto`. Your code doesn't make much sense as it stands.